# Choosing an item from two groups with rules

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose a person is told to choose houses and apartments to own with such rules: must own 2 houses (from 6 target houses) and 3 apartments (from 5 target apartments). How many choices can the person make?

So, from seeing such similar problems the answer is $6\choose{2}$$\times$ $ 5\choose3 $. My question is why isnt it the left one $\frac{6\cdot5\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot3}{5!}$? My "justification" of having that as an answer is the following: we pick 2 house so that gives 6 $\times$ 5 ways, then we pick 3 apartments which gives 5 $\times$ 4 $\times$ 3, then we'll multiply them together. But then we'll have $5!$ arrangements with the same composition, hence we divide it by $5!$. So why is this way of thinking incorrect?

[image]

Comment: Not all of the $5!$ arrangements are consistent with the rules.  The way you have specified the choices, the first two must be houses and the last three apartments.  Hence you should have $2!\times 3!$ in the denominator.

Comment: As a cheap example to illustrate the problem, suppose you had one house and one apartment to chose from. Obviously the number of ways to choose is $1$ since all choices are forced on you.  But your method would yield $\frac {1\times 1}{2!}=\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, i don't quite fathom the line "The way you have specified the choices, the first two must be houses and the last three apartments. " Isn't multiplication independent of order?

Comment: Please study the example I wrote out.  In your $(6\times 5)\times (5\times 4\times 3)$ the first two terms reflect the choices for houses, the last three reflect the choices for apartments. That is critical.

Comment: Suppose some different numeric values : Need to choose 2 houses (out of 3) and  3 apartments (out of 4) ; your method will give $\frac{3 \times 2 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2}{5!}$ = 1.2 solutions. Problem : the result of your formula is not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select your 2 houses from 6 and then select 3 apartments from 5, without loss of generality you choose them in some order, for example $H_1, H_2, A_1, A_2, A_3$. Clearly, this is the same selection as $H_2, H_1, A_3, A_1, A_2$, so we have double counted this configuration. But we have not counted configurations which aren't $H, H, A, A, A$, since all of our selections are 2 houses and then 3 apartments. For example, none of our configurations are $A_1, A_2, A_3, H_1, H_2$, so we don't need to remove this from our count.

The houses and apartments aren't going into the same box, we choose them separately and they don't affect each other. How many houses can we pick? Well there are $\frac{6 \times 5}{2}$ ways to pick 2 objects from 6. Similarly, $\frac{5 \times 4 \times 3}{3!}$ ways to pick 3 apartments from 5.

The key is that we aren't putting these choices into one of 5 boxes - we put a house into one of 2 and an apartment into one of three. We can't put a house into an apartment box, and vice versa. So, we don't need to correct by dividing through by $5!$, since we cannot mix all 5 objects with each other.

I hope that makes some sense, let me know if anything isn't clear!